# How to replace System.out.println as return when parsing JSON ?

Tags: java, arrays, json, for-loop, return

```
 String jsonString = readJsonFile(filePath);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
         JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

         for (int i =0; i < result.length(); i++){
             JSONObject j = result.getJSONObject(i);
             String s = j.getString("sentence");
             int id = j.getInt("id");
             String txtFile = j.getString("txtfile");
             System.out.println("Sentence is:: " + s);
             System.out.println("Id is:: " + id);
             System.out.println("text file is:: " + txtFile);

         }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

currently, the above code is able to print out all the records. However, I would like to change the system.out.println into return variables such as return ID, return txtFile, return sentence. How to do that?

Comment: Once you `return`, usually it breaks out of the loop. May I suggest you store these related variables in a data structure, and returning it when the loop is completed.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. the aim of using return variable, I would like to display the id, txtfile and sentence separately ,not display it in a list.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You may wish to refer to the answers where you wrap each loop's data (i.e. id, txtfile, sentence) as an object, store it in a list and return it (assuming your posted code is a method) to have it iterated and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Object. use an arraylist to store your object and use it later.

```
public class myItem{
   String sentence;
   int id;
   String txtfile;

   public myItem(){
   }

   public String getSentence(){
       return sentence;
   }
   public setSentence(String s){
      this.sentence = sentence;
   }
}


public void yourFunction(){
   try {
       ArrayList <myItem> myList = new ArrayList();

     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
     JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

     for (int i =0; i < result.length(); i++){
         JSONObject j = result.getJSONObject(i);
         String s = j.getString("sentence");

         myItem newItem = new myItem();
         newItem.setSentence(s);

         myList.add(newItem);

     }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what Zhi Kai said in the comment.
PS. I can't comment yet so I'm writing this as an answer.

Create a POJO and u se data structure. In your case you are using a for loop so I assume you need to return a list of values from your JSONArray.

Here's what you can do.

```
String jsonString = readJsonFile(filePath);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

            List<YourObject> yourObjectToReturn = new ArrayList<YourObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                YourObject yourObject = new YourObject();
                JSONObject j = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String s = j.getString("sentence");
                int id = j.getInt("id");
                String txtFile = j.getString("txtfile");
                yourObject.setId(id);
                yourObject.setTxtFile(txtFile);
                yourObject.setSentence(s);
                yourObjectToReturn.add(yourObject);

            }
            return yourObjectToReturn;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Updated:

```
public class YourObject {

    private String id;
    private String txtFile;
    private String sentence;

    public int getId() {
         return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTxtFile() {
        return txtFile;
    }
    public void setTxtFile(String txtFile) {
        this.txtFile = txtFile;
    }
    public String getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }
    public void setSentence(String sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }
}

public List<YourObject> returnObject(){
        String jsonString = readJsonFile(filePath);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

            List<YourObject> yourObjectToReturn = new ArrayList<YourObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                YourObject yourObject = new YourObject();
                JSONObject j = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String s = j.getString("sentence");
                int id = j.getInt("id");
                String txtFile = j.getString("txtfile");
                yourObject.setId(id);
                yourObject.setTxtFile(txtFile);
                yourObject.setSentence(s);
                yourObjectToReturn.add(yourObject);

            }
            return yourObjectToReturn;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u specify how to create List<YourObject>

Comment: Hi I updated my answer. What you need to do is first create a class/model. The one the I created is named YourObject, just rename it. Then on your method set the return type to List<YourObject>. Then as you can see on every iteration on your for loop I created a new instance of YourObject and set the values then add it to List<YourObject>